# Play framework 2.6 Java unable to compile on new Mac

Tags: java, sbt, playframework-2.0, jetbrains-ide

So My old mac died and I bought a new one which I setup using migration utility and a time machine backup.

I use IntelliJ and have quite a number of Play 2 projects which no longer compile either in IntelliJ or command line using sbt compile.

I am getting mainly errors in `xxxx.scala.html` templates

eg

index. scala.html:10:2: not found: value head

referring to

```
@head(title = title)
```

Please anyone who can help get my projects compiling again as I am falling so far behind.

Comment: does it compile when running sbt from command line?

Comment: it does and i subsequently resolved

Answer (score 0):

So basically i had to trash all my intelij projects and start over rebuilding them as new from existing source and then let sbt re run and they came right